# Bootstrap double navbar not collapsing properly

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I took help from this link: http://www.bootply.com/lJgThXaVXi# when bulding my double navbar, and the effect I have is the same as in this example. However, When my navbar collapses I get 2 buttons instead of 1 (the example only get one collapse-button that shows the data from both navbars).

Also, when I press the collapse-button of `navbar1` it shows everything in `navbar1`, however when I press the collapse-button in `navbar2`, that triggers the collapse-button of `navbar1`. Ive been going over the code in the example in detail and can not find anything I do differently.

Basically I wish for 1 collapse button showing all the information from both navbars.

Code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="/Default.aspx" class="navbar-brand">Logo</a>

                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li><a href="/AddSite.aspx">Add site</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" style="background-color:red">
                        <div class="navbar-form" role="search">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSearch" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Search" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonSearch" CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClick="search_click" runat="server"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="background-color:blue">
                        <li >
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonRegister" runat="server" OnClick="Register">Register</asp:LinkButton></li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonLogin" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal" runat="server">Log in</asp:LinkButton></li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonLogout" runat="server" OnClick="Logout">Log out</asp:LinkButton></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END OF FIRST NAVBAR -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li><a href="/AddSite.aspx">Add site</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two collapse buttons in your code. Remove one (of these):

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

Also, I created a demo of a double nav bar collapsing with one button (that I use), using the bootstrap demo navbars:

[**My Bootstrap Double Top Nav Bars**](http://www.bootply.com/jb1NZzlYKK)

Here's the relevant code:

```
<div class="navwrap">
    <!-- first navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top no-bottom-margin">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <span class="navbar-brand">Brand</span>
                <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-right">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- second navbar -->
    <div class="navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse nested-nav global-nav" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the addition of this CSS rule:

```
.no-bottom-margin{margin-bottom:0;}
```

HTH,

-Ted

Comment: Ive tried this, If I remove one then sure, there will only be one button, but it will also only show the contents on 1 navbar

Comment: See my demo, and the HTML I just added to my answer. :)

Comment: Hi, I will take a look. Just from first impression. What is "navWrap"? Also, you dont set a padding for your bottom bar, how does it stay underneath the top one? Global-nav and nested-nav also seem to be custom?

Comment: I think I found my problem. Seems the "fixed-navbar" does not work with this solution. If I change it to static it works. Makes sense. I guess Ill have to do static instead then. Still dont understand why the one in the example works but not mine. Oh well. Thanks!

Comment: Oh the `.navwrap` div was just for my implementation. Glad to help :)